# Методы управление набором объектов

Tags: шаблоны-проектирования, php

Привет всем.

Какие есть способы управления набором объектов (созданных от разных классов)?
Может посоветуете что-то почитать (статьи, раздел книги).
Как добавить/удалить метод/свойство к массиву этих объектов?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не разбираюсь в паттернах, но может попробовать сделать класс-наследник от некоего вашего базового класса (`CBase`) + класса, с которым надо работать. Тогда объекты разных классов будут иметь общие свойства от `CBase` и через них управляться.